# SOAP for ''esxcli storage core device detached list''?

Tags: soap, vmware, vsphere, esxi, virtual-disk

I have an ESXi 5.5 installed. After some time, I noticed that there were multiple detached disks. Running the command `esxcli storage core device detached list` returns:

```
naa.6000eb3b4f9264d90000000000001d6a  off
naa.6000eb3b4f9264d90000000000001d98  off
naa.6000eb3b4f9264d90000000000001da5  off
```

I am wondering which is the corresponding SOAP call that triggers this? Or is there any other way to obtain these disks from the Vsphere web client? By analyzing the `hostd.log`, I get the following information message:

```
Result (type vim.EsxCLI.storage.core.device.detached.list.ScsiDetachedDeviceListMap[])
 (wsdl ArrayOfVimEsxCLIstoragecoredevicedetachedlistScsiDetachedDeviceListMap) (kind 19)
```

Also, `ArrayOfVimEsxCLIstoragecoredevicedetachedlistScsiDetachedDeviceListMap` is not part of the WSDL.

Any help would be appreciated!